# Tailwind dose not provide the rejected/purged style list when using the `rejected` option of purgecss

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss, css-purge

in my project I am using nuxtjs with tailwind and I need somehow to get the purged style.
I tried to use the `rejected` option of purgecss (https://purgecss.com/configuration.html#options), but don't know where to get the result.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/majd-albandik/tailwind-purgecss-unused-style-?file=/tailwind.config.js

`tailwind.config.ts` looks like this

```
purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      './pages/**/*.vue',
      './components/**/*.vue',
      './layouts/**/*.vue',
      './plugins/**/*.vue',
      './plugins/**/*.ts',
    ],
    options: {
      rejected: true,
    },
 theme: {
  .......
```

any idea ?
thanx